# Embed Google Earth Flyover using KML or route

Tags: 7, location

Geofield, Openlayers with KML layers all great and am really loving how well this is all put together on Drupal.

Question: on the site http://www.mapmyfitness.com they are using a Google Earth plugin to display a Fly-over of the route. Is there a Drupal module that implements this at all?